# .htaccess in subdir gets ignored by Wordpress' own .htaccess in /

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have a Wordpress installation on the root of an apache (I.E. on `/`) and WP wrote this custom .htaccess:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>`

Now I need to hide a single php script, let's say in `/scritps/hello.php`, I tried a .htaccess in `/scripts` with:
`<files hello.php>

 Order allow,deny

 Deny from all

</files>`

But it gets overriden by WP's .htaccess, and hello.php is shown anyway. (I know this because moving the `scripts` directory out of WP to another vhost on my local environment makes it work.

I want to hide this php file on the live site because it should only be called by cron from the command line, and I can't put the file outside the apache root because that's all I have FTP access to.
And no, I don't have SSH access, someone else's going to set the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the other `.htaccess` from the sub-directory and try putting this in the `.htaccess` in your root directory:

```
<Directory /scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    <Files hello.php>
       Deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either.